# What is LgeGnssLocationProvider and how do I stop it from keeping my phone awake all the time?

Tags: lg, 8.0-oreo, wakelock

After I have upgraded my LG G6 to 8.0 I've had this extremely annoying (partial) wakelock that keeps my phone awake all the time. It's `LgeGnssLocationProvider` according to BBS and is caused by the system. After some research I found out that GNSS stands for Glonass. When I turn of GPS completely this wakelock does not occur. The weird thing is that when GPS is on the wakelock does not happen always, but regularly. I used battery historian to figure out if something specific triggers it but I can't say for sure.

I have been struggling with it for quite some time. I rooted my phone to disable anything that had to do with GNSS but nothing worked. Over at XDA there are no answers either. I'm kind of running out of options. Any ideas on how to at least figure out what is causing this wakelock? Perhaps some way to trigger a notification as soon as the wakelock is detected?

Comment: Just asking, anything preventing you from turning off GPS when not using it?

Comment: According to [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/lgg6/comments/6uzudg/finally_fixed_idle_drain/) you could try disabling `com.lge.gnsslogcat`. Your issue is also mentioned in [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/lgg6/comments/8p6wq0/battery_draining_after_oreo_update/) (apart from the Reddit you started).

Comment: @AndyYan We had this already in now deleted comments. Ortix prefers not to. Though some [tag:automation] could jump in here, of course :)